# sugarcrm - Opening an action item of menu in new tab

Tags: sugarcrm

I am new to Sugar CRM. I have a new item named "Maps" which is in actions under Leads menu. I found for "Maps" in the whole project and found it in menu.ext.php. Here it is assigned to an array variable as a parameter as show below

```
$module_menu[]=Array(
        "http://mydomain/myProject/maps/something.php" ,
        "Maps","Leads");
```

I need to add target="_blank" to the anchor tag of this "Maps" action item so that it opens in a new tab.

Comment: There is nothing built in to Sugar to facilitate this. Your best approach would be to 1) do non-upgrade-safe hacking to the menu generation code or 2) deploy some sort of JavaScript to modify the anchor if the href param is the one you've defined. By far the easiest choice, though, would be to simply show your users how to use Control+Click to automatically open a a link in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks Mathew for your suggestion. However, I had already implemented the logic using approach #1

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the feature using the following code:

```
mysugarcrmDomain\custom\themes\Sugar5\tpls\_headerShortcuts.tpl
```

I have written if-else logic as shown below for the action items

```
{else}
    {foreach from=$SHORTCUT_MENU item=item}
          {if $item.LABEL == "Maps"}
            <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
           <a target="_blank" href="{$item.URL}">{$item.IMAGE}&nbsp;<span>{$item.LABEL}</span></a>
       </span>
          {else}
       <span style="white-space:nowrap;">
           <a href="{$item.URL}">{$item.IMAGE}&nbsp;<span>{$item.LABEL}</span></a>
       </span>
          {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Hope it helps someone in need.

Comment: That's awesome. Since it's in custom/ it's actually upgrade-safe (unless you upgrade to Sugar 7). Nice job.